# Browsers tries to access the HTTPS version instead HTTP - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, browser, https

I have moved a remote WordPress site in my local with Apache and virtual host with export/import the database.
The problem is almost all of my assets redirecting to the HTTPS version of the new domain.

I have this in wp-config:

```
$url = 'http://newdomain.test';
define( 'WP_HOME', $url );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $url );
```

and this in functions.php:

```
$url = 'http://newdomain.test';
update_option( 'siteurl', $url );
update_option( 'home', $url );
```

This is `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have installed a replace DB plugin and replace all `https` with `http`.

In the generated HTML I the proper URLs (like `http://.....`), but in the console I see the same resources failed to load with `https://...`. At the end, they are not loaded.

If I try to access these assets in the browser, there is no redirection.

There is no cache or HTTP to HTTPS plugin.

I have tried and with this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

It is the same with Chrome, Firefox, IE. The cache is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something like that in the past.

Eventually I got to know that some plugin installed on my site that forces HTTPS which replaces URL from HTTP to HTTPS on the fly.

I would suggest you to check if any such plugin installed OR check for Must Use and drop-in plugins as well.

IF you don't find anything then check for Performance OR Security plugins which most likely provide option to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

I hope that helps. Thanks